# value vs type: Code to Determine if a Variable Is Signed or Not

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

I came across this question in a forum. The answer is something like this:

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (a >= 0 && ~a >= 0) 

//Alternatively, assuming the argument is to be a type, one answer would use type casts: 

#define ISUNSIGNED(type) ((type)0 - 1 > 0)
```

I have a few questions regarding this.Why do we need to check `~a >= 0`? What is the second solution all about? I did not understand the statement: "argument is to be a type". More importantly the author states that first `#define` will not work in ANSI C (but will work in K&R C). Why not?

Comment: Regarding the first part: Signed values can also be positive. Hence testing `a >= 0` only is not enough.

Comment: C types are defined in terms of *values*, not *representations*. The only exceptions are *unsigned integral values*, for which you can assume the specific binary representation to be what you always thought it was. Consequently, you should only use bitwise operations on unsigned integral types. Everything else will give you unpredictable (implementation-defined or undefined) results.

Comment: Just edited my answer to include an explanation for the new promotion rules not working in ANSI C.

Comment: @Kerrek: Not really. There are only 3 legal representations for signed types. As long as you check that a bitwise-ops-based solution is correct for the 3 possible representations, it's 100% portable. One thing to watch out for though is that ~0 can be undefined behavior on non-twos-complement systems without a negative zero.

Comment: @maxpayne: It should be noted that both of these macros are really bad ways to test if an expression/type is signed. There are much better ways to do it, such as `(1?-1:(a))<0`. Also note that all of these methods will fail for smaller-than-int types due to integer promotion issues.

Comment: @R Can you kindly explain the logic behind (1?-1:(a))<0 ?

Comment: @maxpayne Disregarding integer promotions, the type of `(1?-1:(a))` is the type of `a`. Thus `(1?-1:(a))` has the value −1 converted to the type of `a`. This type is unsigned iff the value is non-negative. I initially thought that this wouldn't work, but indeed, `(1?-1:(a))<0` seems a correct solution. I gave an answer with a similar solution. A difference is that in my case, `a` is evaluated, but not with `(1?-1:(a))<0`, which may be better or not, depending on the context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (a >= 0 && ~a >= 0)
```

For a signed value which is positive, `a >= 0` will be true (obviously) and `~a >= 0` will be false since we've flipped the bits so the sign bit is now set, resulting in a negative value. The entire expression is therefore false.

For a signed value which is negative, `a >= 0` will be false (obviously) and the rest of the expression will not be evaluated; the overall result for the expression is false.

For an unsigned value, `a >= 0` will **always** be true (obviously, since unsigned values can't be negative). If we flip the bits then `~a >= 0` is also true, since even with the most significant bit (the sign bit) set to 1, it's still treated as a positive value.

So, the expression returns true if the original value and its bitwise inverse are both positive, i.e. it's an unsigned value.

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(type) ((type)0 - 1 > 0)
```

This is to be called with a type rather than a value: `ISUNSIGNED(int)` or `ISUNSIGNED(unsigned int)`, for example.

For an `int`, the code expands to

```
((int)0 - 1 > 0)
```

which is false, since `-1` is not greater than `0`.

For an `unsigned int`, the code expands to

```
((unsigned int)0 - 1 > 0)
```

The signed `1` and `0` literals in the expression are promoted to `unsigned` to match the first `0`, so the entire expression is evaluated as an unsigned comparison. `0 - 1` in unsigned arithmetic will wrap around resulting in the largest possible unsigned value (all bits set to 1), which is greater than 0, so the result is true.

As to why it would work with K&R C, but not ANSI C, maybe [this article](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/SUNWspro/c-compiler/transition/tguide.doc.html) can shed some light:

> When an unsigned char or unsigned short is widened, the result type is
>   int if an int is large enough to represent all the values of the
>   smaller type. Otherwise, the result type is unsigned int. The value
>   preserving rule produces the least surprise arithmetic result for most
>   expressions.

I guess that means that when comparing an `unsigned short` to `0`, for example, the unsigned value is converted to a `signed int` which breaks the behaviour of the macro.

You can probably work around this by having `(a-a)` which evaluates to either signed or unsigned zero as appropriate, instead of the literal `0` which is always signed.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you kindly tell me what I can do to prevent integer promotions as pointed out by @Artefacto's answer? i.e how do i write the macro in ANSI C?

Comment: So the macro changes to #define ISUNSIGNED(a) (a >= a-a && ~a >= a-a) ?

Comment: Yes, but wrap the (a-a) in brackets for readability and safety!

Comment: I don't know why you'd think changing 0 for `a-a` would make a difference. The integer promotions apply also to the operands binary operator `-` and even if it didn't and `(unsigned char)a - (unsigned char)a` actually had type `unsigned char` (it doesn't, it already has type `int`), the promotion would still happen when the `>=` operator was to be evaluated.

Comment: `(a >= 0 && ~a >= 0)` will give true instead of false in one's complement if `a` is 0 of a signed type. To support one's complement, it seems that the following will work: `((a >= 0 && ~a >= 0) || (~0 == 0 && ~(0*a)))`.

Comment: I've added an answer with a better correct solution.

Comment: `((type)0 - 1 > 0)` will not work correctly for promoted types, like `char` or `short`, sine integral promotion to `int` will result in signed arithmetic regardless of whether the original type was signed. Why did you decide to go `(type)0 - 1` route instead of just `((type)-1 > 0)`?

Answer (score 4):

The tricks with bit-flipping are cute, but if you want to know the signedness of something there are more straightforward ways to do it.  Signedness is the property of a type, not a value.  To determine if a variable is signed, you can ask your compiler if `-1`, cast to that type, is less than `0`, like so:

```
#define issigned(t) (((t)(-1)) < 0)
```

If you want to know this for a particular *variable*, you can ask the compiler for the type of that variable:

```
issigned(typeof(v))
```

Comment: Except that `typeof` is not standard, at least not currently (in C11). Try with `gcc -std=c11` for instance.

Answer (score 3):

For the first macro: If a value is positive (`>= 0`), its bitwise negation must be negative in 2-complement, iff it is singed. An unsigned value will remain positive:

```
~64 == -65 (signed)
~64 == 191 (unsigneD)
```

For the second: if you pass a type to the marco, it checks if this type can hold singed values. For singed types, `0-1 == -1`, for unsigned, it is a positive value:

```
(char) 0-1 == -1
(unsigned char) 0-1 == 255
```

Answer (score 3):

The check for `~a >= 0` relies on flipping the signed bit. The logic is as follows:

- if the number is negative, it cannot be unsigned, so `a >= 0` returns false.
- if it is positive, it's either signed or unsigned.
- if this is unsigned, applying `~ a` will result in the maximum unsigned value - a, still a positive unsigned number.
- if it is signed, the sign bit will be negated, yielding a negative value.

In fact, I think it can be true that `a >= 0 && ~a >= 0` and still the number be signed. This is because there may be a negative zero. In particular, for one's complement a value of all zeros represents `0`, while the representation negated (all 1's) will be negative 0 (or a trap representation).

There's also the problem of integer promotions:

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

Integer promotions apply to "object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int" and "[a] bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int." They are used with both with the unary operator `~` and in the "usual arithmetic conversions", which encompass the first comparison, so they apply here.

So an `unsigned char` will be promoted to an `int`, therefore becoming signed while it was originally unsigned.

For instance, this will give the wrong result:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (a >= 0 && ~a >= 0)
void main(void) {
    unsigned char uc = 8;
    printf("%d", ISUNSIGNED(uc));
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.How do I rectify this in ANSI C? i.e how to I modify the macro so that it is not affected by integer promotions?

Answer (score 1):

The answer `(a >= 0 && ~a >= 0)` proposed in the question is bad as it depends on the integer representation, and in particular it does not work in ones' complement if `a` is 0 of signed type. Here's a correct, portable way of doing things.

First, if `T` is an integer type, one can use the following macro:

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(T) ((T) -1 > 0)
```

Therefore, for the version with a value as an argument, if the type of the value `a` is at least an `int` (to avoid integer promotions, which may change the signedness of the type), the following macro can be used:

```
#define ISUNSIGNED(a) (0*(a) - 1 > 0)
```

It does not depend on the representation of integers, thus it is compatible with all integer representations allowed by the ISO C standard (two's complement, ones' complement, and sign-magnitude).

Answer (score 0):

The first #define works on a variable name.  The second #define works on a type name. (Obviously, if you intended to use both in the same program you'd have to give them distinct names.)

I don't offhand know why either wouldn't work with ANSI C.

Comment: the author mentioned something about "new promotion rules"

Comment: I'm pretty sure I once (or twice) did something akin to #1 in C++.  I don't recall the precise expression I used, though.